# Powershell script runs but throws error "cannot find file specified"

Tags: powershell

it runs the script up until the if clause (for running url) I cannot include the other url here but the script is

```
"welcome, want to go to site?"

$goyn=read-host -prompt "enter y or n"

if($goyn -eq 'y'){
start-process -Filepath chrome.exe -ArgumentList www.google.ca
}
else{"continue on your journey of awesomeness"}


Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName localhost |
Select-Object -Property CSName,@{n="Last Booted";
e={[Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}}
```

for the start-process it throws the error "cannot find file specified followed by the path for $profile. wanted a quicker way of of getting to my work service page.

Comment: Powershell generally requires full paths for referenced files.

Comment: specified the full path and it still throws the error (using the path for iexplorer instead as that is the browser for the other computers on network) seems to have issue with start-process maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So figured it out. it did not like start-process not one bit no matter how outrageously obvious I made the path. So I used the start cmdlet instead and put site in single quotes. Code looks like this:

```
"welcome, want to go to site?"

$goyn=read-host -prompt "enter y or n"

if($goyn -eq 'y'){
start 'www.google.ca'
}
else{"continue on your journey of awesomeness"}


Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName localhost |
Select-Object -Property CSName,@{n="Last Booted";
e={[Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify full path to `chrome.exe` and other used items. E.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Application\chrome.exe`. Adjust %PATH% otherwise. But I'd better specify full path.